# cpp lambda default capture by value does not behave as expected

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to cpp programming and got a bit confused by the default lambda capture [=]. From the cpp doc that it should capture the variable used within lambda by copy.

[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

> = (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by copy).

However the following program shows that the variable captured actually got modified instead of making a copy.

```
#include <atomic>
 
class A {
 public:
  A() : value_{0} {}
  
  void increase() {
    auto inc = [=](){
      value_++;
    };
    
    inc();
  }
  
  int value_;
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   
   std::cout << "value before: " << a.value_ << std::endl;
   
   a.increase();
   
   std::cout << "value after: " << a.value_ << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
value before: 0
value after: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, missed the next sentence in the doc

> The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either capture default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always captured by reference, even if the capture default is =.